# php7.0 Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, php7

I have Ubuntu 15.10.

I'm trying to install php7.0

I executed :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0 

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

### The Reason

The [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/) provides PHP packages only for [supported releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) 
WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

To set the language to UTF-8:

```
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```